# Odd Python 3.4 output behaviour with lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm getting odd results when running a program from the command line. I'm using 3.4.1 (Anaconda release).

Here's the code snippet:

```
inFileList = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], 101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112]]
for eachRow in inFileList:
    for eachItem in eachRow:
        print(eachItem)
```

It works fine interactively. However, when I make a Python program out of it (by doing the following):

```
def main():
    inFileList = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],[101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112]]
    for eachRow in inFileList:
        for eachItem in eachRow:
            print(eachItem)
    print (inFileList)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I get an output on the screen that finishes fine, but outputs hundreds of repeating 'nonsense' values earlier in the cycle. Here's the end of the output:

```
[hundreds of values that gradually change...] [...end of output is:]
367
367
367
367
367
1115
1115
1115
1115
1115
1115
1115
1115
1115
1115
1115
1115
1115
12
101
102
103
104
105
106
107
108
109
110
111
112

[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112]]
```

Now I did tidy this up to provide a more presentable output, and as a side effect my error goes away:

```
from __future__ import print_function
def main():
    inFileList = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],[101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112]]
    for eachRow in inFileList:
        for eachItem in eachRow:
            print(eachItem, end= ' ')
    print (inFileList)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And I get the expected output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112

[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112]]
```

So my problem is fixed. But what was I doing wrong so I can avoid making the same mistake in the future?

Comment: I do not get that behavior with the first program. you sitll getting the same behavior with the first program?

Comment: Works for me, no odd behavior. Besides, you have a syntax error in your snippet of code: the colon after `main()` is missing. Are you sure you have posted the same code you had launched?

Comment: Same for me - works fine - yes missing colon after main()

Comment: one `[` is missing too

Comment: where is one `[` missing?

Comment: Are you sure that you execute the code with python 3.4? Print is already a function in 3.4, so there should be no need to import it from __future__.

Comment: Thanks for correcting the lost colon (it took me a while to format the text with the markup editor, and I must have lost it while trying to get this right).

Yes, I have the same problem. I can simply change print(eachItem, end= ' ') to print(eachItem) and it re-appears.

Comment: Re: comment from Ser Jothan Chanes.
Maybe this a pointer to my issue - I wonder if I've got everything setup cleanly? I'm definitely running 3.4.1 (though I do have 2.7.6 installed as well, for compatibility reasons). 

Of course, there's more to my environment than I said (my apologies for not declaring everything) because I'm developing using Pycharm. I'll eliminate that as a factor.

Comment: I was running 2.7.6 inside the Pycharm terminal. When I run 3.4.1 I can't repeat my problem.
Let's not waste any more of peoples' time (except for my own!) - thanks for all of your observations and feedback.